# Ignore backup files in projectile

Tags: projectile

How to ignore emacs backup (*~) files in projectile?
My code does not work.

```el
(use-package projectile
  :config
  (progn
    (setq projectile-globally-ignored-files
          (append '(
                "*.pyc"
                "*.class"
                "*~"
                )
              projectile-globally-ignored-files))
    (projectile-global-mode)
    (setq projectile-completion-system 'helm)
    (helm-projectile-on)
    (setq projectile-enable-caching t)
    (defconst projectile-mode-line-lighter " P")
    )
  )
```

When I call `helm-projectile-find-other-file` I always see backup files which is quite annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `projectile-globally-ignored-files` should be populated with literal filename suffixes, not [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). Admittedly the variable's documentation does not make this obvious.

So your code could be rewritten as

```el
(use-package projectile
  :config
  (setq projectile-completion-system 'helm
        projectile-enable-caching    t
        projectile-globally-ignored-files
        (append '(".pyc"
                  ".class"
                  "~")
                projectile-globally-ignored-files))
  (projectile-mode)
  (helm-projectile-on)
  (defconst projectile-mode-line-lighter " P"))
```

My other suggested changes to your code, as seen in my example, are the following:

- Use `projectile-mode` instead of obsolete `projectile-global-mode`.
- Call `setq` once.
- Do not put closing parentheses on lines by themselves, as per the [Emacs Coding Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html).
- Remove redundant `progn` from `use-package` `:config` clause.

By the way, is the `projectile-mode-line-lighter` necessary? I don't see `projectile` making use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience, finding this very confusing. Eventually, I figure out that I had to run `M-x projectile-invalidate-cache` for the changes to `projectile-globally-ignored-*` to be heeded.